# @Nullable vs. Generics (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, jsr305

I want to bring a utility method to Java 8. The method named `max` is defined as follows:

```
@SafeVarargs
public static final <E extends Comparable<E>> E max(final E... elements) {
    E result = null; // error
    for(final E e : elements) {
        if(result == null || result.compareTo(e) < 0) {
            result = e;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now Eclipse shows an error:

> Null type mismatch (type annotations): `null` is not compatible to the free type variable `E`.

I would have thought that adding `@Nullable`to the definition of `result` should remove the error, but this is apparently not the case. Even if I additionally annotate the whole method with `@Nullable`, the error persists.

By the way I'm using jsr-305.jar from FindBugs and have configured Eclipse to honor `javax.annotation.Nonnull` as well as `javax.annotation.Nullable`. Edit: I run Eclipse Luna 4.4.2 and Oracle JDK 8 build 1.8.0_25-b17 on Lubuntu.

Now for my question: Where does the error come from? How do I get rid of it while maintaining the benefit of both the annotation and the generic type definition?

Edit: I just added an example project where the default eclipse annotations are used, and it appears to somewhat work (apart from generating a warning at the `result == null` because it incorrectly infers that result can only be null at that point). So this appears to be an Eclipse problem with non-default annotation classes. I re-tested it with my own copy of Eclipse's `Nullable` annotation, and got the same error as above.

Comment: Hmm...what's your java8 version? I don't get this error on jdk 8u25

Comment: No errors on Eclipse Luna 4.4.1, running on JDK 8u31.

Comment: Do you also use the FindBugs annotation jars?

Comment: The error looks like java 9 where a type param may be a primitive type; `List<int>``?

Comment: What version of Eclipse are you using? This should not be an error

Comment: I'm running exact same version of Java and Eclipse and no error this side.

Comment: @Chris: I'm using 4.4.2.

Comment: @Joop Eggen: I'd be very surprised if that turns out to be the cause.

Comment: @Ian2thedv: Do you have annotation-based null analysis enabled?

Comment: Actually, could you update your question with the full eclipse error instead of the partial one. I have a feeling that it is not a compile error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where does the error come from?

I found this in the [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftask-using_null_type_annotations.htm):

> A type variable corresponding to an unconstrained type parameter
>   requires pessimistic checking in order to guarantee safety with all
>   legal substitutions: this type can neither be assumed to be nullable
>   nor nonnull.
>
> ```
> class C<T extends Number> {
>     int consume(T t) {
>         return t.intValue(); // NOT OK since T could be nullable
>     }
>     T provide() {
>         return null;         // NOT OK since T could require nonnull
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> The last point may look surprising at first, but please see that an unconstrained type parameter implies that we may not assume
>   anything about the nullness of the type represented by the
>   corresponding type variable. Even more: we must actively support
>   nullable and nonnull types. On the other hand this simply extends the
>   existing rule that the only type being compatible with an unbounded
>   type variable is the type variable itself. To explain this situation
>   in the context of null analysis, the compiler will raise the following
>   error against the return in provide():

When instantiating a generic type or when invoking a generic method, the constraints put forward by the type parameter must be observed.

> How do I get rid of it while maintaining the benefit of both the annotation and the generic type definition?

Add @Nullable to `<E extends Comparable<E>>`, like so

```
@SafeVarargs
public static final  <@Nullable E extends Comparable<E>> E max(final E... elements) {
    E result = null; // no error
    for(final E e : elements) {
        if(result == null || result.compareTo(e) < 0) {
            result = e;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Note however that eclipse still errors on javax.annotation.Nullable, because it lacks a @Target annotation. This is quite unfortunate.

Answer (score 1):

Tja, Optional. How else if the varargs array is empty?

```
public static final <E extends Comparable<E>> Optional<E> max(final E... elements) {
    Optional<E> result = Optional.empty();
    for(final E e : elements) {
        if(!result.isPresent() || result.get().compareTo(e) < 0) {
            result.set(e);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Or require at least one argument.

```
public static final <E extends Comparable<E>> E max(final E first, final E... elements) {
    E result = first;
    for (final E e : elements) {
        if (/*result != null ||*/ result.compareTo(e) < 0) {
            result = e;
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Requiring at least one argument (or requiring that the arguments be non-null) is unfortunately out of the question. I also have the solution with Optional (In fact I can use Arrays.stream(elements).max()), but I cannot simply change API.